# How to left join two tables on specific conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have two tables Price(Type, Values) and Product(Seat) and some values.

```
Price        | Product
-------------+---------
Type  Values | Seat
S     4      | FO
P     6      | CA
             | FA
```

I know that [FO] and [CA] belong to type [P], and [FA] belongs to type [S]. How can I join these tables and shows associated type and values:

**Results**

```
Seat  Type  Values
----- ----- -----------
FO    P     6
CA    P     6
FA    S     4
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please don't use a link to show us your data; include the detail in your question as `text`.

Comment: Also specify the expected result. Take a look at [mcve]!

Comment: Create another table to store the "_I know that [FO] and [CA] belong to type [P], and [FA] belongs to type [S],_" relations.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a derived table to store the mapping between `price` and `seat`. This is easily extensible when new requirements come up.

```
SELECT pri.*, pro.*
FROM price pri
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'FO' seat, 'P' price
    UNION ALL SELECT 'CA' seat, 'P' price
    UNION ALL SELECT 'FA' seat, 'S' price
) map ON map.pri = pri.price
INNER JOIN product pro ON pro.seat = map.pro
```

This can be simplified by using the `VALUES()` syntax:

```
SELECT pri.*, pro.*
FROM price pri
INNER JOIN ( 
    VALUES('FO', 'P'), ('CA', 'P'), ('FA', 'S') 
) AS map(seat, price) ON map.pri = pri.price
INNER JOIN product pro ON pro.seat = map.pro
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` the tables like this:

```
select pr.seat, sum(p.value)
from price p join
     product pr
     on pr.seat in ('FO', 'CA') and p.type = 'P' or
        pr.seat in ('FA') and p.type = 'S'
group by pr.seat;
```

That said, you should have a proper table that connects the seats to the products, probably called `ProductSeats` with one row per product and matching seat.